# entity framework select records do not exists in join table or field is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am building an `c# lambda` with `Entity Framework`

I have two tables with inner join relationship...(`Order` and `MarketOrder`). `OrderID` is the PK on `Order Table` and the FK on `MarketOrder Table.`

Resuming my Model is like this

```html
 public  class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
    
        public virtual MarketOrder MarketOrders { get; set; }
}


 public class MarketOrder
    {
        [Key]
        public int MarketOrderID { get; set; } // One sequence for all system market orders.
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I need to select records do not exists in join table or is exists having field `MarketOrder.Status is null`

I taste this

```
db.Order
.Where(c => !db.MarketOrder
    .Select(b => b.OrderID)
    .Contains(c.OrderID)
);
```

I works fine when do not exists in other table but I can not use it in case it exists with Status == null.

Whe the relationship is One to Many. In Order class I have the property

```
 public virtual List<MarketOrder> MarketOrders { get; set; }

var aa =(from order in db.OrderFunds
from marketOrder in order.MarketOrders.DefaultIfEmpty()
where marketOrder.OrderID == null || marketOrder.Status == null).ToList();
```

it Works fine.

I have the problem when the relationship is `One To One`. In Order Class I have the property

```
 public virtual MarketOrder MarketOrders { get; set; }
```

the line

```
order.MarketOrders.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Does not work. `order.MarketOrders` do not have the method `DefaultIfEmpty()`. If I use `order.MarketOrders.ToString().DefaultIfEmpty()` The clause `where marketOrder.OrderID` do not have property `OrderID`

How can I solved it.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript-framework, this question does not seem to have anything to do with it.

Comment: Can you post your model Order and MarketOrder

Comment: Try a left outer join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: HI, I add class Model. Thanks

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty works on a List or IEnumerable, not a Single Object. you should be able to check if the Order.MarketOrder == NULL || Order.MarketOrder.Status == NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Order.Where(o => o.MarketOrder?.Status == null)
```

Same as

```
db.Order.Where(o => o.MarketOrder == null || o.MarketOrder.Status == null)
```

Comment: MarketOrder? this means that MarketOrder can be null?

Comment: yes, it's newer C#7 maybe. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: note that the first approach won't work, since the conditional operator ? is not supported in l2sql.

Comment: I did not know that, I use it often but it must always be on objects.